# what is wrong with this code when dealing with large values of "long"?

Tags: java, math, puzzle

I wrote an utility class to encode numbers in a custom [numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) with base N. As any self-respecting Java programmer I then wrote a unit test to check that the code works as expected (for any number I could throw at it).

It turned out, that for small numbers, it worked. However, for sufficiently large numbers, the tests failed.

The code:

```
public class EncodeUtil {

    private String symbols;

    private boolean isCaseSensitive;
    private boolean useDefaultSymbols;

    private int[] symbolLookup = new int[255];

    public EncodeUtil() {
        this(true);
    }

    public EncodeUtil(boolean isCaseSensitive) {
        this.useDefaultSymbols = true;
        setCaseSensitive(isCaseSensitive);
    }

    public EncodeUtil(boolean isCaseSensitive, String symbols) {
        this.useDefaultSymbols = false;
        setCaseSensitive(isCaseSensitive);
        setSymbols(symbols);
    }

    public void setSymbols(String symbols) {
        this.symbols = symbols;
        fillLookupArray();
    }

    public void setCaseSensitive(boolean isCaseSensitive) {
        this.isCaseSensitive = isCaseSensitive;
        if (useDefaultSymbols) {
            setSymbols(makeAlphaNumericString(isCaseSensitive));
        }
    }

    private void fillLookupArray() {
        //reset lookup array
        for (int i = 0; i < symbolLookup.length; i++) {
            symbolLookup[i] = -1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length(); i++) {
            char c = symbols.charAt(i);
            if (symbolLookup[(int) c] == -1) {
                symbolLookup[(int) c] = i;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate symbol:" + c);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String makeAlphaNumericString(boolean caseSensitive) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
        int caseDiff = 'a' - 'A';
        for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
            sb.append((char) i);
            if (caseSensitive) sb.append((char) (i + caseDiff));
        }
        for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) {
            sb.append((char) i);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String encodeNumber(long decNum) {
        return encodeNumber(decNum, 0);
    }

    public String encodeNumber(long decNum, int minLen) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(20);
        long num = decNum;
        long mod = 0;
        int base = symbols.length();
        do {
            mod = num % base;
            result.append(symbols.charAt((int) mod));
            num = Math.round(Math.floor((num-mod) / base));
        } while (num > 0);
        if (result.length() < minLen) {
            for (int i = result.length(); i < minLen; i++) {
                result.append(symbols.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public long decodeNumber(String encNum) {
        if (encNum == null) return 0;
        if (!isCaseSensitive) encNum = encNum.toUpperCase();
        long result = 0;
        int base = symbols.length();
        long multiplier = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < encNum.length(); i++) {
            char c = encNum.charAt(i);
            int pos = symbolLookup[(int) c];
            if (pos == -1) {
                String debugValue = encNum.substring(0, i) + "[" + c + "]";
                if (encNum.length()-1 > i) {
                    debugValue += encNum.substring(i + 1);
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "invalid symbol '" + c + "' at position " 
                    + (i+1) + ": " + debugValue);
            } else {
                result += pos * multiplier;
                multiplier = multiplier * base;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbols;
    }

}
```

The test:

```
public class EncodeUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testRoundTrip() throws Exception {
        //for some reason, numbers larger than this range will not be decoded correctly
        //maybe some bug in JVM with arithmetic with long values?
        //tried also BigDecimal, didn't make any difference
        //anyway, it is highly improbable that we ever need such large numbers
        long value = 288230376151711743L;
        test(value, new EncodeUtil());
        test(value, new EncodeUtil(false));
        test(value, new EncodeUtil(true, "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoundTripMax() throws Exception {
        //this will fail, see above
        test(Long.MAX_VALUE, new EncodeUtil());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoundTripGettingCloserToMax() throws Exception {
        //here we test different values, getting closer to Long.MAX_VALUE
        //this will fail, see above
        EncodeUtil util = new EncodeUtil();
        for (long i = 1000; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(i);
            test(Long.MAX_VALUE / i, util);
        }
    }

    private void test(long number, EncodeUtil util) throws Exception {
        String encoded = util.encodeNumber(number);
        long result = util.decodeNumber(encoded);
        long diff = number - result;
        //System.out.println(number + " = " + encoded + " diff " + diff);
        assertEquals("original=" + number + ", result=" + result + ", encoded=" + encoded, 0, diff);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why things start failing when the values get large? I also tried BigInteger, but it did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: First problem with your code: ASCII doesn't have 255 values...

Comment: More seriously - you've presented a lot of code, with little indication of what you've already investigated. For example, have you tried to work out whether the problem is within the encoder or the decoder?

Comment: The number in your test case is 2^60.  Long.MAX_VALUE is 2^63-1.  If I were you, I'd look for some place where you're multiplying your number by approximately 2^3.

Comment: As the code is now it is very prone to failure, and difficult to read.

Comment: Hint: claiming that the language/library that is used by many, many people all the time has a flaw as fundamental as this one is an easy way to get downvotes (at least that's what I guess is the reason for the downvotes, because otherwise it's a well-written question).

Comment: ok, I made the title less "offensive" and also removed the reference to 255 ASCII symbols (silly me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using floating point maths in your `encodeNumber` method, which makes your code rely on the precision of the `double` type.

Replacing

```
num = Math.round(Math.floor((num-mod) / base));
```

with

```
num = (num - mod) / base;
```

Makes the tests pass. Actually

```
num = num / base;
```

Should work just as well (thought experiment: what is `19 / 10` when `/` is integer division?).

Comment: And what would be the alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You have a conversion to double in your code, which could be generating strange results for large values.

```
num = Math.round(Math.floor((num-mod) / base));
```

that would be my first port of call.